# Write a function returning most recent date

Tags: c, pointers

**Task**: Suppose I have a list of dates in the format of `Tue, 27 Mar 2018 04:46:22 GMT`, and I want to find the most recent date of a given list. I have created a function that compares every two dates and outputs the latest one.

**Code** for the function with some debugging prints

```
char *max_time(char *t1, char *t2) {
    if (t1 == NULL && t2 == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "t1, t2 are null");
        exit(1);
    }
    
    if (t1 == NULL) {
        return t2;
    } else if (t2 == NULL) {
        return t1;
    }
    
    
    printf("Incoming time1: %s, size: %zu\n", t1, strlen(t1));
    printf("Incoming time2: %s, size: %zu\n", t2, strlen(t2));

    struct tm tm1, tm2;
    time_t time1, time2;
    double diff;

    memset(&tm1, 0, sizeof(struct tm));
    memset(&tm2, 0, sizeof(struct tm));
    memset(&time1, 0, sizeof(time_t));
    memset(&time2, 0, sizeof(time_t));

    strptime(t1, "%a, %d %b %Y %X %Z", &tm1);
    strptime(t2, "%a, %d %b %Y %X %Z", &tm2);
    time1 = mktime(&tm1);
    time2 = mktime(&tm2);

    /* debug */
    char str1[50];
    char str2[50];
    strftime(str1, 50, "%a, %d %b %Y %X %Z", &tm1);
    strftime(str2, 50, "%a, %d %b %Y %X %Z", &tm2);
    printf("Time1: %s\n", str1);
    printf("Time2: %s\n", str2);
    /* end debugging */


    diff = difftime(time1, time2);
    printf("Time diff: %f\n", diff);
    if (diff > 0) {
        return t1;
    } else {
        return t2;
    }
}
```

**Usage**

```
char *t1[] = {"Tue, 27 Mar 2018 04:46:22 GMT\r",
                  "Tue, 27 Mar 2018 04:47:46 GMT\r",
                  "Tue, 27 Mar 2018 04:57:17 GMT\r",
                  "Tue, 27 Mar 2018 04:49:31 GMT\r",
                  "Tue, 27 Mar 2018 04:48:46 GMT\r",
                  "Mon, 26 Mar 2018 03:44:55 GMT\r"};

    int i = 0;
    char *res = NULL;
    for(i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        res = max_time(res, t1[i]);
        printf("Res: %s\n", res);
    }
```

It did work out for the sample case, but in real deployment it fails. Part of the report shows as following.

**Bug reporting**: The deployment outputs, it fails to convert char into timestamps
[image]

The difference between the sample and real deployment is data structure, the date data are stored in a linked list (list->date) in deployment case. According to the report, it looks like that I failed to pass char array to `strptime`, if that was true, very likely I did something incorrect when moving the pointers. But I'm not sure where it happens exactly. If you have another way to achieve the same outcome, feel free to comment.

Comment: The `memset`s don't look right. `time1` is not a `struct tm`.

Comment: When running the debug the "size" debug output indicates strlen 29. But your "deployment" screenshot indicates 30. Could there be a newline in there, maybe?

It would be useful if you in future questions would define exactly what "deployment" means in the context.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]. Without it, your question is off-topic.

Comment: @lash it won't affect the result, just tested.

Answer (score 0):

The first issue is the memset(&time1, 0, sizeof(struct tm));
But eventually it will write over *diff* and *str1*, so it shouldn't be a cause of the problem.

But:

As you are using "human" readable months naming, you should make sure that the time locale is set to the same on prod and on dev systems.

Try to check it out using setlocale() function:

```
#include <locale.h>
printf("TS_LOCALE %s", setlocale(LC_TIME, NULL));
```

If it differs, just set it to the same value as you have on dev machine.